# WooCommerce Composite Products Variable Product Dropdown Not Displaying Options

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

WordPress 4.5
WooCommerce Version: 2.5.5
WooCommerce Composite Products Version: 3.6.3

**Edit Product page in admin dashboard WooCommerce Composite Products**

I'm making a "variable" product. I expect that if I define two attributes (Natural gas and LP gas), and check the "Used for variations" box, and then in the Variations tab I see the two new attributes listed as variations, that these should appear in the product page dropdown for "Gas type".

**Product page as public web page**

Instead, I see Gas type with a select box dropdown, which says "choose an option", but when I click "choose an option", the select box dropdown doesn't have any of the options or variations I created in the Edit Product page.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the row corresponding to your variation (***#7206*** or ***#7205***) to show the hidden menu, then you have to set a price (`Regular Price` field). It is required for the values to be displayed.